# Алгоритм ускорения / торможения в игре под Android

Tags: android

Друзья, всем привет. Я начинающий разработчик игр под Android. Делаю первые шаги и мне нужна Ваша помощь. Нужно реализовать **ускорение с последующим торможением**, не совсем знаю, как правильно это выразить.

У менять есть подробное описание проблемы вот тут: **[Документ](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h7FSyxHNX8ar7kL1X6fyzWKVRkT8retjt_zibZhJZqU/edit?usp=sharing)**

Там можно оставлять комментарии, и можно тут )

Дополнение:
Когда нажимаешь на область справа от ракетки, она должна двигаться туда с начальной скоростью, которая равномерно затухает до полного торможения при достижении цели.

**p.s.** Надеюсь вопрос по адресу )

Comment: Думаю стоит полазать на спец сайтах аля gamedev.ru. Сама по себе задача к Андроид мало отношения имеет. С таким же успехом можно теги добавить: c++, c, c#, javasript и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное у Вас есть таймер, который вызывает просчет какой-то внутренней логики с последующим вызовом отрисовки? Таймер скорее всего вызывается с равными интервалами. Теперь, вспоминая курс по физике за класс 7-8, понимаем, что растояние, которое будет проходить ракета за единицу времени должно уменьшаться. Тогда и будет замедление.

Как я бы это сделал по простому:

- рассчитываем координаты между ракетой (rx, ry) и пальцем (fx, fy)
- расчитываем разницу (абсолютную - (dx, dy) = (abs(rx-fx), abs(ry-fy)).
- если dx или dy меньше некого порога, то приехали (rx, ry) = (fx, fy). Порог подбираем экспериментально на первых порах.
- в противном случае, смещение приравниваем 10 части от координат. (fx, fy) = (fx + dx/10, fy + dy/10); знак +, если rx > fx, и минус в противном случае. Аналогично для другой координаты (но независимо).

Если нужно будет ускорить/замедлить - то просто подбираем правильный коэффициент приращение (то есть, не 10 часть, а 20 - будет замедление). Так как растояние будет с каждым шагом уменьшаться, то и приращение будет уменьшаться. Также нужно не забыть ту ситуацию, что приращение может быть равным нулю (если математику сделать целочисленной), но я рекомендую делать ее вещественной - будет проще.

Я подозреваю, что в Вашем случае будет достаточно одной y координаты, но это ничего не меняет в вышеприведенном алгоритме.

Comment: Очень хорошо описан процесс, спасибо. Да с одной координатой - Х, но я, кажется, все понял.

Comment: Что-то он у меня прям улетает куда-то (неконтролируемо). А почему смещение мы приравниваем к координате X + десятая часть расстояния между ними? Получается offset всегда будет расти?

Comment: offset будет уменьшеться, так как будет уменьшаться расстояние между пальцем и ракетой. Видимо Вы всегда приплюсовываете или неверно рассчитываете знак.

Comment: Так fx же не будет уменьшаться. А значит всегда будет прирост:
int dX = Math.abs(rx- fx); // Расстояние до цели
if (rx > fx) offset = fx + dx/10;
else offset = fx - dx/10;

Comment: ох, перекрутили мой ответ вверх тормашками...


    int dx = Math.abs(rx- fx); // Расстояние до цели
    if (dx <= 10)
        rx = fx;
    else if (rx > fx)
        rx = rx + dx/10;
    else
        rx = rx - dx/10;

Comment: Все сделал, просто скорость была слишком высокой. Пришлось offset *= 0.01 ))

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то речь идет о том, как написать формулу, которая бы:

1. С начала движения придавала ракетке некую заданную начальную скорость
2. К концу движения плавно гасила бы скорость

В этом случае, если смотреть в терминах `S(t)` график зависимости пройденного пути от времени (таймера) будет [выглядеть примерно так](http://yotx.ru/graph.ashx?clr0=000000&exp0=x*x%2f%28exp%28x%29-1%29&mix=0&max=10&asx=on&u=mm&nx=t&aiy=on&asy=on&ny=s&iw=600&ih=400&ict=png&aa=on)

В данном примере ракетка начинает двигаться с `t=0` и останавливается на `t=10`

Это график функции: `A*t*t/(exp(B*t)-C)` - где:
`А` - задает крутизну взлета графика (начальную скорость ракетки)
`B` - крутизну падения графика (скорость торможения)
`С` - регулирует местоположение остановки

Вам остается подобрать коэффициенты A, B, C и прикрутить расчет местоположения ракетки в зависимости от вашего таймера.

Comment: Очень хороший пример, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать графический движок, то к нему можно прикрутить `Box2D`. К ракете будет привязан физический мир и соответственно она будет иметь

> ускорение с последующим торможением.

Comment: Спасибо, пока так изучаю построение общей модели проектирования )

Comment: @frops, стоит поглядеть в `sdk` в `sample` - `LunarLander`.

Comment: @monomi Там подобная ситуация?

Comment: @frops, это семпл из сдкашки с игрой, в которой по нажатию на кнопку ракета поднимается с ускорением вверх и при отпускании - сбавляя скорость, падает вниз. примерная физика там описана.